# Notifying calling thread when all asynchronous child threads used for transformation have completed in spring

Tags: spring, concurrency

I need to transform data in child threads which are managed by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. Is there a way the calling thread can be notified when all asynchronous child threads have completed transformation in spring.

Approach outside spring:
One way I can think of(outside spring) is using Executor Service. Each invocation to transformerChannel.send will happen in a Callable which can return a Future.

```
i.e. public <TransformedData> call(){
```

sendDataToTransformer();
}

```
ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
    List<Future< DataToBeTransformed >> future=new ArrayList<Future< DataToBeTransformed >>();
    List<Callable< DataToBeTransformed >> callList = new ArrayList<Callable<DataToBeTransformed>>();

future=pool.invokeAll(callList);
```

Is there a way to do anything similar in spring using transformer tag. The transformer method in this case is not a part of any Callable. The invocation to send method of transformer channel is not being done in any callable.